# Regex to replace character inside an image tag

Tags: php, regex

I would like to change like below

from

```
{% set desc =  Lorem ipsum dolor sit &amp; amet, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt <img src="https://google_image.jpg&amp;ver=1 %}
```

To

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit &amp; amet, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt <img src="https://google_image.jpg&ver=1
```

I want to conver &amp to & if it is inside image tag only.

Comment: it's not so easy in one step, and regex is thought to be not ideal for xml, but you could of course do it in two steps.   step1- get the image tag.  step2. replace any &amp.  Like `<img src=[^>]*>` should get the img tag but some white space might throw that one off. Or for step1 you could use an xml parser that accepts css selectors. php has phpquery https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpquery/   Doing it all in one go might be a slightly less simple regex, you'd have to use lookahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**your provided code doesn't have endings for img tag.**

I assumed your code would be

```
{% set desc =  Lorem ipsum dolor sit &amp; amet, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt <img src="https://google_image.jpg&amp;ver=1"> %}
```

#### Regex for your requirement would be:

```
{\%.*?=[ ]*(.*?)<img(.*?)src="(.*?)&amp;(.*?)">[ ]*\%}
```

#### and replacement would be

```
$1 <img$2src="$3&$4">
```

Check this https://regexr.com/3lq75

---

## In case your question has correct original code, i.e.,

```
{% set desc =  Lorem ipsum dolor sit &amp; amet, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt <img src="https://google_image.jpg&amp;ver=1 %}
```

#### Regex would be:

```
{\%.*?=[ ]*(.*?)<img(.*?)src="(.*?)&amp;(.*?)[ ]*\%}
```

#### and replacement would be:

```
$1 <img$2src="$3&$4
```

https://regexr.com/3lq78